# Why do I have to use NaN in a constructor and can't use null? typescript

Tags: typescript, null, numbers, nan, gojs

I'm using the library GoJS in my Angular project.

When I want to return a `new Size()` from gojs with only one parameter, the other one has to be NaN:

I'm doing something like `new Size(NaN, height)`

The constructor of Size() looks like this: `constructor(w?: number, h?: number);`

Why can't I use `null` instead of `NaN` ?

When using `null` the browser returns `Error: Invalid arguments to Size constructor: null, 200`

I don't have a problem to fix, I just don't understand why it wouldn't work with `null`

Comment: You can't pass in `null` but the type signature will let you pass in `undefined`, I don't know if GoJS will actually handle that case but the compiler should be satisfied.

Comment: To expand on what Ferrucio said about, when you have a type like `w?: number` it is the same as saying `w: number | undefined`. So `null` isn't accepted, but `undefined` will be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `NaN` has type `number`, where `null` has type `null`. You cannot pass `null` where `number` is required. You could be doing that if type of this constructor would be `constructor(w?: number | null, h?: number | null)`, then using it as `new Size(null, null)` would be type correct.

```
let a: number = NaN; // NaN is number
a = null; // error as null is not number

let b: number | null = NaN; // fine as before
b = null; // also fine as null is explicitly define in the type
```

Also `Error: Invalid arguments to Size constructor: null, 200` is runtime error, it means that inside the constructor code is checking arguments types by probably `typeof` and raise this exception if any of the arguments will not be number.